# Sabre API Error "errorCode": "WARN.RAF.APPLICATION"

Tags: php, laravel-8, sabre

I am building a Travel Website. I have successful integrated the APIs for Sabre.
However if I do not pass retun date in query or if return date is null I get error.

After lot of troubleshooting I decided to check on Sabre Dev studio
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search/reference-documentation#/default/instaFlightsSearch

If I leave the return date empty or do not pass it. I get the same result on Sabre site as well.:
{
"status": "Complete",
"reportingSystem": "raf",
"timeStamp": "2024-03-11T11:58:15Z",
"type": "Application",
"errorCode": "WARN.RAF.APPLICATION",
"instance": "raf-raf-blue-5f55d58779-926dx-default",
"message": "No results were found"
},

Though if i scroll below I can see the flights results, however my Laravel application does move ahead and and I get the same error.

How can I move ahead even with this error or fix it. Though it is also on sabre dev studio

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search/reference-documentation#/default/instaFlightsSearch

Same error on Sabre dev studio as well

Comment: If it does the same thing with the studio API, I would suggest contacting the devs to find out the workaround. It could be a bug in their system.

Comment: Yes, the same error is on on Dev studio as well, also checked with postman, it took my hours to realize there was no error in my code. Will try Nad ipen a ticket. I saw same error posted with same kind of issue 5 years back, I don't think they will fix it.